# How to get sales tax calculations with Stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am following the steps from this [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/taxes/collect-taxes) for my checkout process so I can use Stripe to calculate the sales tax for me based on the country and postal code.

I created a customer and pending subscription as per steps 3 and 4. At this point, I want to get the response from the command below which should tell me the automatic_tax status (complete, requires_location_inputs, or failed). However, I get an error in response instead. When I go to my Stripe dashboard, I do see an invoice that is marked as open. Why is the response not as expected?

**COMMAND**

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/upcoming \
  -u sk_test_<STRIPE API TEST KEY>: \
  -d "customer"="{{ CUSTOMER_ID }}" \
  -d subscription_items[0][price]="{{ PRICE_ID }}" \
  -d subscription_items[0][quantity]=1 \
  -d "automatic_tax[enabled]"=true
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
 "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such invoice: 'upcoming'",
    "param": "id",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming invoice endpoint is a `GET` endpoint only. [Ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming?lang=curl)

If you add `--request GET` to your `curl` command, that should work. It's currently trying to POST to [update an existing invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update?lang=curl) with id 'upcoming' which is not valid.